# Running 18.04 but still getting warning: Security updates... ...ment Stack ended on 2016-08-04

Tags: upgrade, kernel

I updated my Ubuntu to 18.04.4 LTS but if i'm loggin into this machine with SSH i'm getting the warning:

```
WARNING: Security updates for your current Hardware Enablement Stack
ended on 2016-08-04:
 * http://wiki.ubuntu.com/1404_HWE_EOL

To upgrade to a supported (or longer-supported) configuration:

* Upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS by running:
sudo do-release-upgrade 

OR

* Switch to the current security-supported stack by running:
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-xenial linux-generic-lts-xenial

and reboot your system.
```

When i run `sudo do-release-upgrade` there are no updates available to install. When i run `sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-xenial linux-generic-lts-xenial` i'm getting these errors:

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-xenial linux-generic-lts-xenial
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-generic-lts-xenial
E: Unable to locate package linux-generic-lts-xenial
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

```
$ uname -a
Linux stash-server 5.3.0-46-generic #38~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 31 04:17:56 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to askubuntu. Please include the output of `lsb_release -a` and `uname -a` in your question. And do not try to install linux-image-generic-lts-xenial if you are on 18.04.

Comment: @Bruni Thanks for your comment. I have edited my question with the output.